# get text from an link with onclick in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to get text from an link with onclick ?

my code :

```
<a href='#' onclick='clickfunc()'>link</a>

 function clickfunc() {
        var t = text();
        alert(t);
    }
```

text = **link**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try this

```
 <a href='#' onclick='clickfunc(this)'>link</a>

 function clickfunc(obj) {
    var t = $(obj).text();
    alert(t);
 }
```

well, it is always better and recommended to avoid inline javascript(`onclick()`).. rather you can use

```
$('a').click(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

or to be more specific...give an id to `<a>` and use id selector

```
 <a href='#' id='someId'>link</a>

 $('#someId').click(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<a href='#' onclick='clickfunc(this)'>link</a>

clickfunc = function(link) {
  var t = link.innerText || link.textContent;
  alert(t);
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reGYn/2/)

Comment: Use `link.textContent || link.innerText` for full browser support. Or stick to jQuery’s `.text()`

Comment: @David: You are right about textContent. jQuery was not mentioned so I guessed poster wanted to do without.

Answer (score 3):

try this with vanilla javascript

```
<a href='#' onclick='clickfunc(this)'>link</a>

 function clickfunc(this) {
    var t = this.innerText;
    alert(t);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

**HTML**

```
<a href='#' onclick='clickfunc(this)'>link</a>
```

**JS**

```
function clickfunc(obj) {
    var t = $(obj).text();
    alert(t);
}
```

Demo: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KdZLa/)

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you can do it this way.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    alert($(this).text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
<a href='#' id="mylink" onclick='clickfunc()'>link</a>
```

**js**

```
function clickfunc() {
            var l = document.getElementById('mylink').href; //for link
            var t = document.getElementById('mylink').innerHTML; //for innerhtml
            alert(l);
            alert(t);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this easy using jQuery

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
  var txt = $(e.target).text();
  alert(txt);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you use javascript not jquery,
do the following

```
<a href='#' onclick='clickfunc(this)'>link</a>

 function clickfunc(obj) {
        var t = obj.innerText;
        alert(t);
    }
```